# get all attributes in html string in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I have string in HTML format and i am trying to get all the attributes and its values using Jsoup.

String is

```
String string= 
"<button class=submit btn primary-btn flex-table-btn js-submit type=submit>Sign in</button>";

 Document doc = Jsoup.parse(string);
    try {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Attributes attrs = doc.attributes();

        for( org.jsoup.nodes.Element element : doc.getAllElements() )
        {
              for( Attribute attribute : element.attributes() )
              {
                  System.out.println( attribute.getKey() +  " --::-- "+attribute.getValue()  ); 
              }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

My desired output is ::

```
key: **class** , Value is: **submit btn primary-btn flex-table-btn js-submit**

key: **type** , Value is: **submit**
```

But what I get is this

`key: class , Value is: submit
key: btn , Value is: 
key: primary-btn , Value is: 
key: flex-table-btn , Value is: 
key: js-submit , Value is: 
key: type , Value is: submit`

This is because of the quotes. If I use

```
String string= 
"<button class='submit btn primary-btn flex-table-btn js-submit' type='submit'>       Sign in</button>";
```

I will get my desired output.But I am trying to get without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You *can't* do it without the quotes, because the quotes are not optional. Without the quotes, the HTML you've quoted describes an element with **one** class (`submit`) and a series of non-class, invalid additional attributes with names like `btn`, `flex-table`, etc., and that's how any browser will interpret it, just as JSoup is doing. If those are meant to be additional classes on the element, quotes are **required**.

From [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0):

> **Unquoted attribute value syntax**
>
> The attribute name, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by a single U+003D EQUALS SIGN character, followed by zero or more space characters, followed by the attribute value, which, in addition to the requirements given above for attribute values, ***must not contain any literal space characters***, any U+0022 QUOTATION MARK characters ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE characters ('), "=" (U+003D) characters, "<" (U+003C) characters, ">" (U+003E) characters, or U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT characters (`), and must not be the empty string.

Note that *"must not contain any literal space characters"* part I've emphasized.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with `Jsoup`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(HTML);
List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>(); //record tags

for(Element e : doc.getAllElements()){      // all elements in html

    tags.add(e.tagName().toLowerCase());    // add each tag in tags List
    //System.out.println("Tag: "+ e.tag()+" attributes = "+e.attributes());  // attributes with values in string
    //System.out.println("Tag: "+ e.tag()+" attributes = "+e.attributes().asList()); //attributes in List<Attribute>

    for(Attribute att : e.attributes().asList()){ // for each tag get all attributes in one List<Attribute>
        System.out.print("Key: "+att.getKey()+ " , Value: "+att.getValue());
        System.out.println();
    }
}

System.out.println("*****************");
System.out.println("All Tags = "+tags);
System.out.println("Distinct Tags = "+ new HashSet<String>(tags));
```